# Make msiexec wait until the installation completes

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I am trying to run a powershell script to install an application using msiexec.exe.

> msiexec.exe /a "C:\Users\tempuser\Desktop\AppInstall.msi" /passive wait

So I want the installation to be completed before moving on the rest of the commands in order to prevent messing up the whole automation process.

Once i run my script, it pops out a windows installer menu that shows all the msiexec options. I think I used the wait parameter incorrectly at the end of the line. Already spent so much googling for any solutions... I'd appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$myJob = Start-Job {[your msiexec call]}
Wait-Job $myJob
```

Or

```
$params = @{
        "FilePath" = "$Env:SystemRoot\system32\msiexec.exe"
        "ArgumentList" = @(
        "/x"
        "$($productCodeGUID)"
        "/qn"
        "REMOVE=ALL"
        "/norestart"
        )
        "Verb" = "runas"
        "PassThru" = $true
    }

    $uninstaller = start-process @params
    $uninstaller.WaitForExit()
```

Tweak the `params` to match your needs. I like the second approach as it makes the arguments easier to read in lengthy code.

Running as a process or job may make no difference to you, but if they do then just pick the one best suited to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/a "C:\Users\tempuser\Desktop\AppInstall.msi" /passive'`

Source: https://powershellexplained.com/2016-10-21-powershell-installing-msi-files/

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38482518/389424 but this one is a one-liner for those who prefer them + using the exact same arguments as OP

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the 'start' command with the /wait switch

start /wait msiexec -passive -i package.msi

Comment: Well... sort of.  When I tried that "start..." command line as-is, it got confused.  The "Start-Process" commandlet seemed to want the -passive and -i commands for itself.  I had to remove the ambiguity by wrapping msiexec's args in an -ArgumentList option argument, thus:

start /wait msiexec -ArgumentList "-passive -i package.msi"